# Is OM MA NI PADME HUM flag useful?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

[image: OM MA NI PADME HUM]
[image]

May I use this Tibetan flag above door and will this protect house from negative and bad energy?
I know importance of chanting **OM MA NI PADME HUM.**
So is it helpful or just ***feng shui*** thing?
I thought to ask before having one above the main door.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps guard your and others' hearts as a summons to mindfulness it is quite useful.

If it is intended to ward off a jet falling from the sky it is not so useful.

If you are looking for a guard against "Negative and bad energy (black magic)" you are looking for a [place without fear](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.56/en/sujato).

Comment: Thank you I know there's no miracle like things it could do. But that I've asked about "*negative* and  *bad energy* (black magic)".

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I've added a sutta link for you to study.  Notice that a jet that crashes might have done so from the negative and bad energy of a terrorist. Each of us has that seed inside us of negative and bad energy, however. The sutta says this better than I can.

Comment: Oh yes the source is a mind. Thank you so much.